# calling setInterval after clear Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on my personal project, and have problem with resuming setInterval after I cleared it.

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    elem=document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0];
    if (typeof elem == 'undefined')
    {
        return;
    }
    clearInterval(interval);
    //my code
    //element is undefined again
    return setInterval(interval) //Want to start setInterval again, but nothing happens
}, 10);
```

Comment: You have to set it again. A interval can't be resumed.

Comment: `return setInterval(interval)` turns into `setInterval(setInterval(interval))` in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `interval` variable just stores the ID of your interval, so you can easily clear it later on. It won't store your function though.

For that to work, store your interval function in a variable so you can restart it like this:

```
var interval;
var intervalCallback = function() {
  elem = document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0];
  if (typeof elem == 'undefined') {
    return;
  }
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(intervalCallback, 10);
};
interval = setInterval(intervalCallback, 10);
```